# Create a floating circle with a drop shadow inside of a square div with only css code

Tags: css

So here's my perdiciment.
I have 4 divs inside of a container div.

```
<div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Each of the nested divs are squares. I need to somehow create a floating yellow circle with a drop shadow inside each square div. The trick is I cannot edit the HTML. It all has to be done in css.

I've played around with borders but that just breaks the square.
And box shadows don't make a nice clean circle.

Any ideas?

Comment: so you want to have a circle inside the square without adding any html tags?

Comment: something is fishy whenever someone says they can't edit certain files in their project....

Answer (score 4):

You can make a circle with a `box-shadow` inside the square using [`:after` pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) as follows:

```css
div div {
    height:     50px;
    width:      50px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin:     20px;
}

div div:after {
    content:  " ";
    height:   40px;
    width:    40px;
    display:  block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background:    yellow;
    box-shadow:    5px 5px 5px #888888;
}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cxCcC/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!